# VIM: Skip a word for visual selection

Tags: vim, selection

Since discovering VIM, I find it simpler to type SQL in lower case and then to make the words that I need uppercase. Is there a way to skip over a word in visual mode such that it will not be made part of the selection, so that I might select all the MySQL keywords and then perform `U` on them? For instance, assuming this SQL query:

```
select a.name, b.userid from someTable a inner join anotherTable b on a.someField=b.someOtherField group by a.randomField sort on b.yetAnotherField desc;
```

I would like to select the first word (select), skip two words, select another word (from), skip two word, select two words (inner join), and so on.

I do have Ctrl-6 mapped to upper case letters (to avoid having Caps Lock activated in Normal mode), but I really do prefer to type out the SQL in lower case first and then to "fix" it. I also know that the lower case SQL is valid, but coding practices dictate that it should all be upper case in code.

I tried to write a function that would traverse the current line and uppercase all the MySQL keywords. However, even if I do go that route, I would still like to know the solution to skipping words in Visual mode as I see other uses for it as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going to move your cursor along the whole line, another route is to not use *visual* mode at all:

1. With the cursor on `select`, type `gUiw` to turn it into `SELECT`.
2. Move to `from` with multiple `w` (inneficient, maybe) or with `/fr<CR>` (faster, less typing, maybe).
3. Hit `.` to repeat the last edit and turn `from` into `FROM`.
4. Repeat…

Comment: Thank you, I did not know about `gUiw` or even that case could be altered in Normal mode. After doing the first I can easily `w` and `.` to get the result that I need. Thanks!

Comment: In your example, you'd need to hit `w` 8 times to reach `from`. I'd suggest to use `W`, instead, to skip dotted words.

Comment: Thanks, that is a helpful VIM. Quite deep is the VIM rabbit hole!

Answer (score 3):

Are you asking whether it is possible to select multiple disjoint regions in visual mode?

If so, this cannot be done in plain Vim, but the [Multiselect plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=953) claims to do just that.  (Disclaimer: I have not used this plugin myself.)

If this workflow is something you find yourself doing regularly then I think a functional solution is more efficient. (You could even trigger it automatically on file save, once it is robust enough.)

Comment: I'm torn. Though you did answer exactly my question, another answer solved my issue "the VIM way". [As it is suggested to select the answer that solves the issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27669/which-answer-should-i-accept-that-which-solved-my-problem-or-that-which-solved) I will select that one. As Henry Ford once quipped, had he asked his customers what they wanted they would have told him to produce a faster horse. Apparently I am that naive, I should have asked "what to do in this situation" rather than "how to realise this solution that I _think_ might work". Forgive me?

Comment: No problem! One of the great things about this site is that you often get questions answered that are much broader than the one you asked!